# CSS and HTML boxes smallest on top but not in order

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right, this is slightly hard to explain but what I'm after is as follows:

I have a database of posts that will go into an HTML page. Obviously all these posts will be different sizes so the boxes containing them will be different sizes too.

What I'm after is a way to make these boxes all appear to fit nicely in with each other, as in the picture below for example. If the first post is a small one then it will begin a line of small boxes for example. And they won't necessarily all be the same height either. In the picture each post is numbered to show where it comes in the array of posts.

See the illustration I made here:

[image]

Is this possible? I'm assuming I'll need some Javascript in there probably, and JQuery is preferable.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You say that the posts will not be the same height, but your drawing is the same height. I think you should make a new drawing with a real data inside, this way you will see things that you don't see now.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a best fit algorithm yes? In the picture you show a configuration with 7 posts, grouped into sets of 3.  Is this always the case? Can there be a set of 4 in a group or maybe 1 if it is large enough?

Comment: @Vivek Chandra - Your comment is stupid. This is a serious question and a proof of that is the brilliant answer by Simon. So go troll some other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're willing to go with a Javascript solution, I've found that the [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin works really well for doing a "best fit" of differently shaped rectangles.

You set it up with markup like:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

You then `float: left` your `.item`s, and attach the Masonry handler to the `#container`:

```
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    ...
  });
});
```

There's also a [no-jQuery version](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) if you're not already using jQuery at all

Comment: Cheers pal, I'll check this out now(: